# How did we get an [italy-weather] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

That seems highly specific. Two questions, both already tagged [italy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/italy) and [weather-and-climate](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weather-and-climate).

https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/italy-weather

can we just get rid of it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes please edit and take them out.

When empty it should disappear.

Comment: I do think it would be funny to have a [rain-in-spain] tag or an [la-smog] tag.

Comment: (Un)fortunately not [friday-in-iceland](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21413) tag